# How to fix Laravel open ssl error on localhost?

Tags: laravel, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have a project on a hosted server. I downloaded the whole Laravel folder, downloaded the same version of PHP to my computer and launched the website in visual studio code using the command php artisan serve.

I get the Error 'Call to undefined function Illuminate\Encryption\openssl_cipher_iv_length()' in the file laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter.php

I have checked and open ssl is not commented out in the php.ini file and the dll is in the php folder.  Do you know how to fix this error?

Comment: did you run `composer install` ?

Comment: Ah thank you that worked.  I added the composer extension in visual studio code.  I downloaded composer from the website which referenced my php folder and created a new php ini file.  Restarted visual studio code and all works now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In visual studio code add the composer extension. Downloaded composer to your local machine which will create a new php.ini file if one does not already exist. Restart visual studio. In the terminal run php artisan serve.